# Find extreme values in relative frequencies

Tags: biostatistics, extreme-value, weibull-distribution

I have the relative frequencies of elements in roughly 450 samples (with varying sample sizes). These elements are organisms in fecal samples.

I am interested in finding extreme values of these relative frequencies per element. In context, this would refer to organisms that occur "too much" or "too little" in the fecal sample, which is informative for the health of the animal the sample comes from.

Would it be good practice to fit a distribution, calculate confidence intervals for the means and mark values outside of that as extreme?

I added an image of the distribution of a few elements as an example. As can be seen, the distributions seem right-skewed heavily. What would be an appropriate distribution to fit? Because of the shape I was thinking of Weibull, though perhaps there are distributions specifically for these situations that I am unaware of.

A more straightforward approach would be simply taking the 5th and 95th percentile. How would results differ in that case?

[image: Distributions of relative frequencies of elements in samples]

Comment: What for? Why do you want to find them? How do you want to use them? Why does it matter? "Extreme" can mean different things depending on the context.

Comment: This is my first question here so thanks for asking for clarification, I have edited my post. 

The elements in the samples represent organisms in fecal samples and extreme values would refer to organisms that are over/under abundant in the sample. This is informative for the health of the animal the samples come from. So for each sample I want to know for which elements their relative frequency is extreme. However, I am unsure how to set the boundary for marking a value extreme.

Comment: Do you aim to investigate each element as such or are you searching for combinations? I think that instead of quantiles I'd probably try something like the outlier rules of boxplots which allow for a varying number of outliers per element which appears more reasonable to me.